Since when do Late Answers reviews require multiple users to complete?
I think this link speaks for itself. Review items in the Late Answers queue always used to require only one user to be completed, and the only way you'd see more than one reviewer on the same review item was if two people were completing it at the same time. The review queues on that item are hours apart, and when I logged in to Puzzling this morning, I saw the red dot in the review queue dropdown indicating that something was still outstanding to be reviewed.
Weirdly, I don't see the same thing happening at Sci-Fi and Fantasy - all recent review items in Late Answers have only been reviewed once (link will work only for high-rep SFF users). I don't have full review tools privileges on many other active sites to check their review queue history, but it's unlikely that such a bug has affected only one site (that would be puzzling indeed), so I'm posting here on main meta to ask what's up.
Why are (some) Late Answers review items suddenly requiring more than one user to be completed?

The "Recommend Deletion" action will complete the review only in case the answer was deleted as result.
If not, the item will still be in review.
In your case, you did not choose "Recommend Deletion", and as result the review was completed. (Otherwise it would have needed one more, as it needs 6 to auto-delete.)

In case I'm wrong and you have another example with multiple reviews without "Recommend Deletion" please share link and I'll try to keep digging.

Ah, that would make sense. (To be precise, I didn't cast a delete vote from the Late Answers review queue, because I did that from the Low Quality Posts review queue and flagged from the Late Answers review queue, but yeah, I "Reviewed" rather than "Recommend[ed] Deletion".)

I see. So "Recommend Deletion" appears to be the only action that might leave the item in the queue.

And it didn't do that in the past: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/112431/timeline (found with this SEDE query, in case you want to dig a bit more)

@Glorfindel isn't it this reported case?

Thanks for refreshing my memory :) I guess that bug is [tag:status-completed] then?

@Glorfindel yup, looks like this, though maybe better check some more cases first.
